# jQuery datatables buttons missing

Tags: reactjs, datatables, create-react-app, datatable-buttons

I can't make buttons in jQuery datatables work.
I have react app created with create-react-app

```
import React from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
// eslint-disable-next-line
import dt from 'datatables.net';
// eslint-disable-next-line
import buttons from 'datatables.net-buttons';

export default (Child, tableId) =>
    class extends React.Component {
        componentDidMount = () => {
            $(`#${tableId}`).DataTable({
                ordering: true,
                info: false,
                pageLength: 10,
                responsive: true,
                dom: '<"buttons"B>lTfgitp',
                buttons: [ 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf' ]
            });
        };

        render = () => <Child {...this.props} />;
    };
```

and the whole [source](https://bitbucket.org/PNAJ/datatables-buttons/commits/ab2ffed228392608577000918ec2b5f84f2103b6#chg-src/WithDataTables.js) to run locally

I've noticed that when I put worng button in configuration: `buttons: [ 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'foobar' ]` i have error in console '`Uncaught Unknown button type: foobar'`
So I gess something is working, but I still can't see buttons.

Comment: My guess is that  you are missing includes.  there are separate includes for various different types of buttons (excel, pdf, etc) in addition to the button include itself.